# C++: Signed or unsigned array indexing?

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, 64-bit

I am in the process of porting a C++ application to x64 from x86. Now, there is a custom array class with functions like GetRowCount(); etc. If these functions return a size_t (and the whole array class would be dealing with size_t for indexing) it would mean I could get (2^64)-1 items in such an array, but if I would utilize a signed ptrdiff_t instead I would lose much of the max array size. My question is basically which types to use: signed or unsigned types for arrays? I have been reading other topics on this but they have been purely focused on indexing.

The problem I see is due to let's say somewhere code looks something like this:

```
[signed/unsigned type] result = customArray.GetRowCount() - a;
```

where in some cases the variable "a" may be signed and in other cases unsigned, and assuming it could be larger than the row count returned. What is then done with the "result" variable I don't know, but it could for instance be used in some further arithmetic operations.

So, to stay out of trouble with mixing signed and unsigned arithmetic and implicit casts in code which utilizes the custom array class, should I in that array class instead be working with ptrdiff_t and thereby also let functions like GetRowCount() return a ptrdiff_t? Or should I use intptr_t, is it more logical?

Here http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0050/ the example shows ptrdiff_t should be used...

However, like stated in the beginning I can then no longer index arrays with up to SIZE_MAX elements since half of the value span of a signed type will be used for negative values.

I hope I am making any sense and would really appreciate some clarification and guidance.
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: How many elements do you think you need?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I would assume that the positive values available by a signed 64-bit type should suffice. But I am just thinking /what if/ - in more general terms. This array class I am talking about in my question is placed in a pretty central library with around 50 - 80 projects utilizing it, and I am not aware of the intrinsic details of how all of these will use the array class. But what I now is that the array class used int before internally and as return value of GetRowCount() etc.

Comment: Use an int where -1 could be used to indicate an invalid value. Do you anticipate having more than 2 billion entries?

Comment: @bvj int falls out of the equation since the point is to make the switch over to x64 and have portable code, so I need a size_t or ptrdiff_t for instance as I understand it, for those types change size according to data model and platform architecture.

Comment: @user2506124: So does `int`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not in the case of LLP64 data model (Used by Windows and visual c++ compiler) int is still 32-bit when application is compiled to x64 and can no longer fully address arrays or store the address of a pointer type. size_t and ptrdiff_t among others will be 32-bit when compiled in x86 mode and 64-bit in x64 mode.

So, that was the point of my question, if wanting to enable 64-bit addressing but try not to mix signed/unsigned arithmetic, should I address with size_t or ptrdiff_t for instance, given by my example above in the main question?

Comment: @user2506124: So, your comment boils down to "no, `int` is not platform-specific, because I can name one platform on which it is always the same"? :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, not really how I meant, because I meant that int is not platform independent. I want it to scale with the platforms - not just be same on one platform configuration. Like, casting from a size_t to int on x86 does not ifer a risk of data truncation but on x64 it would. :)

Anyway, thanks everyone for your comments!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty close to a matter of personal taste.

Some people say any use of an unsigned integral type for anything other than bit manipulation is faulty, and use signed types for all quantities. Others (including the designers of the C++ standard libraries) use unsigned types for counting things. Neither side of the debate has ever proven that the other side are total idiots who can't write decent code (although I think occasional individuals on both sides have claimed they have).

I feel that unless you're going to eliminate unsigned types entirely you might as well copy the standard. If the array is backed by memory then it's unlikely that an implementation will create an array half the size of the address space even on a 32 bit system. On a 64 bit system it's utterly infeasible. If you arrange for your array class to prevent that it's not much of a loss. So the max value of the type isn't really a concern.

However, that's for newly-designed code. If the class is central then you shouldn't change its interface more than necessary. Either continue with `int` or switch to `ptrdiff_t` if you need more capacity. Definitely don't use `intptr_t`. That's for storing addresses, not counts or offsets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Yes, in this case it is central legacy code, and I think you are correct that not changing the interface (or at least as little as possible) is a very good idea.